# Redirect HTTPS to HTTP on localhost only

Tags: .htaccess, http, ssl, https, localhost

I'm working on a website locally that contains https links, so when I click on one of these links it takes me to `https://localhost/...` which doesn't exist as there is no SSL certificate installed.

Is there anything I can add to `.htaccess` that checks if I'm on localhost and if so redirects `https` to `http`? The .htaccess file is used in both local development and production on our server so anything I add mustn't affect the live website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope.

Reason is any rules you put in your htaccess file will only get applied *once the request has been made*, which means it'll only get applied once the `https://localhost/` request is made. If there's nothing listening to the HTTPS port (443) on localhost, then the rules will never get applied.

If port 443 *is* listening for requests on localhost, but it's just a matter of lacking an SSL certificate, the rules still won't get applied until *after the SSL handshake is performed*, which means, you're still going to get the security warning about your certificate.

That being said, the rules you'd want if you had apache listening to port 443 and have a certificate installed is this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for the explanation. I'll look into installing a certificate then. Cheers!

Comment: @AdamMcElroy if you don't mind the overhead (just for local dev), you can look into [mod_proxy_html](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy_html.html) which will allow you to rewrite links *within your content* that that localhost links get turned into http and you don't need to use mod_rewrite